# I have an issue with the ts-migrate

Tags: javascript, typescript, migration

I tried to migrate my .jsx into .tsx (javascript into transcript) with :
`npx -p ts-migrate -c "ts-migrate-full <folder>"`
And I got this error:
`\node_modules\.bin\..\ts-migrate\bin\ts-migrate-full.sh: No such file or directory`
I think it must be a stupid error, but I don't find anything on the web. Some help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error using a Windows Powershell or Windows CMD command line; however, when I ran the command in a git bash shell everything worked fine.